# Form Input Missing in Datatable Exported Data

Tags: datatables

I have this Html:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <div id="product_purchase_report_table_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap">
        <div class="dt-buttons btn-group">
            <a class="btn btn-default buttons-csv buttons-html5 btn-sm" tabindex="0" aria-controls="product_purchase_report_table" href="#">
                <span><i class="fa fa-file-csv" aria-hidden="true"></i> Export to CSV</span>
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-default buttons-excel buttons-html5 btn-sm" tabindex="0" aria-controls="product_purchase_report_table" href="#">
                <span><i class="fa fa-file-excel" aria-hidden="true"></i> Export to Excel</span>
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-default buttons-print btn-sm" tabindex="0" aria-controls="product_purchase_report_table" href="#">
                <span><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i> Print</span>
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-default buttons-collection buttons-colvis btn-sm" tabindex="0" aria-controls="product_purchase_report_table" href="#">
                <span><i class="fa fa-columns" aria-hidden="true"></i> Column visibility</span>
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-default buttons-pdf buttons-html5 btn-sm" tabindex="0" aria-controls="product_purchase_report_table" href="#">
                <span><i class="fa fa-file-pdf" aria-hidden="true"></i> Export to PDF</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="product_purchase_report_table_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
            <label><input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search ..." aria-controls="product_purchase_report_table" /></label>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable" id="product_purchase_report_table" role="grid" aria-describedby="product_purchase_report_table_info">
            <thead>
                <tr role="row">
                    <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="product_purchase_report_table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Date: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 56.7656px;">Date</th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="product_purchase_report_table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Supplier: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 386.305px;">Supplier</th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="product_purchase_report_table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Product: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 104.383px;">Product</th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="product_purchase_report_table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Reference No.: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 103.508px;">Reference No.</th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="product_purchase_report_table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Quantity: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 62.1953px;">Quantity</th>
                    <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="PCs" style="width: 86.0312px;">PCs</th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="product_purchase_report_table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Unit Purchase Price: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 142.883px;">
                        Unit Purchase Price
                    </th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="product_purchase_report_table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Subtotal: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 69.4141px;">Subtotal</th>
                    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="product_purchase_report_table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Average (Kgs) / Pc: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 133.516px;">Average (Kgs) / Pc</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr role="row" class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">02-10-2023</td>
                    <td>
                        mr Omar Salim Mwakuzinya - AUTO REPAIRS
                    </td>
                    <td>01. Whole Chicken</td>
                    <td>5412</td>
                    <td>1200</td>
                    <td style="max-width: 70px !important;" class="mobile">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" value="0.00" name="pcs" type="number" id="pcs" data-code="55" data-value="0.00" style="width: 70px !important;" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>300.00</td>
                    <td>360,000.00</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="even">
                    <td class="sorting_1">02-10-2023</td>
                    <td>
                        mr Omar Salim Mwakuzinya - AUTO REPAIRS
                    </td>
                    <td>11. Gizzard</td>
                    <td>5412</td>
                    <td>3.5</td>
                    <td style="max-width: 70px !important;" class="mobile">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" value="0.00" name="pcs" type="number" id="pcs" data-code="56" data-value="0.00" style="width: 70px !important;" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>200.00</td>
                    <td>700.00</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr class="bg-gray font-17 footer-total text-center">
                    <td colspan="4" rowspan="1">Total:</td>
                    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">1449.06</td>
                    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">204</td>
                    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">297.00</td>
                    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">430,366.68</td>
                    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        <div class="dataTables_info" id="product_purchase_report_table_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 11 of 11 entries</div>
        <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="product_purchase_report_table_paginate">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="paginate_button previous disabled" id="product_purchase_report_table_previous"><a href="#" aria-controls="product_purchase_report_table" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0">Previous</a></li>
                <li class="paginate_button active"><a href="#" aria-controls="product_purchase_report_table" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a></li>
                <li class="paginate_button next disabled" id="product_purchase_report_table_next"><a href="#" aria-controls="product_purchase_report_table" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">Next</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which yields this Datatable:

[image]

My issue is, when I export the data in either way (pdf, excel etc), the form input data (PCs Column) are blank. I do I export the input as text just as the other columns? I need to have all the columns exported inclusing the form input ones. I am using the Datatables CDN library

Comment: You would need to display those inputs as text instead of inputs.  One way to do that would be to have the user save the row, or save all rows, before they export.  Then render the datatable with text fields, not inputs.  So essentially, you have an Edit mode that does not allow export.  Only View mode allows export.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

You can just use this snippet taken from an [existing Datatables forum thread](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/50724/export-values-typed-in-input-box-excelhtml5):

```
body: function ( data, row, column, node ) 
{
return $(data).is("div") ?
$(data).find('input').val():
data;
}
```